# if conditional can't work well ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my javascript code:

```
        $.getJSON('data/pizza.json', function (data) {
        let menu = data.menu;
        let content = ``;
        $.each(menu, function (i, data) {
            console.log(data.kategori == kategori.toLowerCase())
            if (data.kategori==kategori.toLowerCase()) { // this is an error
                content += `<div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-3">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img/pizza/${data.gambar}" alt="img">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold;">${data.nama}</h5>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Rp. ${data.harga},-</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${data.deskripsi}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Pesan</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
            }
        });
        $('#daftar-menu').html(content);
    });
```

This is my html code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="120px"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">All Menu<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pizza<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nasi<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Minuman<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>All Menu</h1>enter code here
    <div class="row" id="daftar-menu">
    </div>
```

> my data
> "menu": [
> {
> "kategori": "pizza",
> "nama": "Meat Lover",
> "deskripsi": "Irisan sosis sapi, daging sapi cincang, burger sapi, sosis ayam.",
> "harga": 49500,
> "gambar": "meat-lover.jpg"
> },
> {
> "kategori": "pizza",
> "nama": "Super Supreme",
> "deskripsi": "Daging ayam dan sapi asap, daging sapi cincang, burger sapi, jamur, paprika merah dan paprika hijau.",
> "harga": 49500,
> "gambar": "supreme.jpg"
> }
> ]

when I click pizza on navbar, the result will show filtered data based on my script. but the result is empty here.

I was suspicious with my if conditional and also I have checked the value and type but still cant get what the error might be

Tmk my conditional is not correct ...

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(data.kategori==kategori.toLowerCase())` on line before `if`?

Comment: false, because data.kategori always undefine

Comment: Can you share the content of `data.menu` ... console.log(data.menu)

Comment: Umm ... What kind of help you're expecting then? I mean you know what is wrong, "_data.kategori always undefined_". You've to fix your data, we can't do that.

Comment: i just check the result on that line,, just ignore about it

Comment: "menu": [
        {
            "kategori": "pizza",
            "nama": "Meat Lover",
            "deskripsi": "Irisan sosis sapi, daging sapi cincang, burger sapi, sosis ayam.",
            "harga": 49500,
            "gambar": "meat-lover.jpg"
        },
        {
            "kategori": "pizza",
            "nama": "Super Supreme",
            "deskripsi": "Daging ayam dan sapi asap, daging sapi cincang, burger sapi, jamur, paprika merah dan paprika hijau.",
            "harga": 49500,
            "gambar": "supreme.jpg"
        }

Comment: But the result of the check is, that you've no data.

Comment: but when i console.log on singel line the result is good as same in my data